# Selecting points such that sum of x coordinates = sum of y coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of `Point`s. I need to select a subset of points from it, such that the sum of x coordinates of the points = sum of y coordinates of the points.
If there are many such subsets, the one with largest sum of x coordinates is required.
The sum of x coordinates needs to be reported.

I have written a brute force recursive method, which tests all possibilities.

```
Point[] a = new Point[n];
// ...
private int rec(int i, int x, int y) {
    if (i == n - 1) {
        if (x + a[i].x == y + a[i].y) return x + a[i].x;
        return (x == y) ? x : -1;
    }
    return Math.max(rec(i + 1, x, y), rec(i + 1, x + a[i].x, y + a[i].y));
}
```

The answer is `rec(0, 0, 0)`.

My questions are:

1) Is there a dynamic programming solution for this?
2) If yes, could anyone please explain

Comment: this looks like a variation to 0-1 knapsack problem, so I'd believe that you can only hope for pseudo-polynomial solution using DP.

Comment: Are there any bounds on the coordinates? For example, must they be non-negative?

Comment: Yes, all coordinates are non negative. You can assume that they are < 10^5.

Comment: and how many points are there? Can we do DP on the sum of the coordinates in O(n^2 w^2), where w is the sum of all x's.

Comment: @ile: Number of points are < 10^5, so no, that would not be possible.

Comment: you should have mentioned it. I do not think you can find an exact answer quite fast for the large inputs. So search for "approximations to knapsack problems" (since you have the reduction to subset sum problem" now below.

Answer (score 4):

I have a bit better (than brute force) algorithm.

1. Divided all coordinates into three sets:

   ```
    1: {(x,y): x>y}, 2: {(x,y):x==y}, 3:{(x,y): x lower-than y}
   ```
2. Set `2` have to be always included in the solution.
3. for each (x,y) from `1` define `net=x-y` and for each (x,y) form `3` define `net=y-x`
4. check all possible values you can obtained from `net`s in `1` and `net`s in `3`.
5. then basing on the greatest match it is easy to construct the solution.

Does it make sense?

Comment: basically this is reduced to the well-known [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: I just finished showing the original problem is NP-Hard by reduction from Subset-Sum. It looks as though this problem should be regarded as a Subset-Sum variant.

Answer (score 4):

For each point, set its value to `x - y`.

Now we need to find a set of points whose values sum to 0.

This is exactly [the subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

It is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) (i.e. there is no known polynomial time algorithm for the generic case of the problem), but there exists a pseudo-polynomial time DP solution, which is given on Wikpedia, linked above. A brief summary:

> We define a function `Q(i,s)` to be the value (`true` or `false`) of
>
> ```
> there is a nonempty subset of x1, ..., xi which sums to s
> ```
>
> Then we have the following recurrence:
>
> ```
> Q(1,s) := (x1 == s)
> Q(i,s) := Q(i − 1, s) or (xi == s) or Q(i − 1, s − xi)   for A ≤ s ≤ B
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are unstated constraints, the problem is NP-Hard by polynomial-time reduction of Subset-Sum, an NP-Complete problem.

One of the decision forms of Subset-Sum asks, given a set of integers, X, and an integer s, does any non-empty subset sum to s.

For each element of X, construct a Point whose x value is the element, and whose y value is zero. Construct one additional Point, whose x value is 0 and whose y value is s.

If the result of the equal-sum problem applied to that set of points is 0 or -1, then reject the subset-sum problem. If the result is s, then accept the subset-sum.

Assuming P != NP, or at least that we don't have any polynomial algorithm for any NP-Hard problem, there is no known polynomial-time algorithm for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

just trying to code in java which would be helpful i felt:

**for all i , `diffOfCoordinates[i] = Xi - Yi`**

`list` will have the max points.

```
public void fun(int[] diffOfCoordinates, int indexA, int[] b, int indexB, int sum, List<Integer> list){
       if(indexA == diffOfCoordinates.length){
           if(sum==0){
               if(list.size()<indexB){
                   list.clear();
                   for(int i=0;i<indexB;i++){
                       list.add(b[i]);
                   }
               }
           }
           return;
       }
       b[indexB] = diffOfCoordinates[indexA];
       fun(diffOfCoordinates, indexA+1, b, indexB+1, sum+diffOfCoordinates[indexA], list);
       fun(diffOfCoordinates, indexA+1, b, indexB, sum, list);
   }
```